# Block certain application from accesing PCI serial COM card in Windows XP, how?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Is it possible to prevent a certain application from accessing the hardware? I have two separate PCI cards installed and they provice 4 COM ports in total. Sadly this one application blocks all 4 of them on start. Can I force it to see only one PCI device and keep other two COM ports free for other applications? I can't move from Windows XP on this offline Lab computer because licenses.

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that this one application, when started and only when it starts,
blocks all PCI it finds, the simplest solution would not to have these ports
enabled when it starts.

So only enable them when you need these ports, and hopefully the application will not
detect the newly enabled ports.

One tool you might use is
[COMDisable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/819036/overview-of-the-comdisable-tool),
described as:

> With the COMDisable tool, you can view a list of available COM ports on your computer. You can also disable or enable the COM ports on your computer without manually editing the registry.

(I have never used this tool and do not know how well it works.)

---

Under XP you can also set a port to be non-detected on boot:

- Remove the hidden, system, and read-only attributes from the file `C:\Boot.ini`
  and make a backup copy of it
- Using a text editor such as Notepad, open the `Boot.ini` file and
  add a line such as `/fastdetect:com3,com4`
- Save `Boot.ini` and quit Notepad
- Restore the hidden, system, and read-only attributes
- Shut down and restart Windows.

To re-enable the ports, connect your device(s) and run scan for devices
which should pick it up.

[Devcon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon)
might be used for scanning or other operations.
You may download this
[.cab file](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/e/4/6e481b67-54af-4340-a534-25de4229cfc6/support.cab)
from which you may extract `devcon.exe`.

(Note: I don't have XP for testing.)

Comment: ComDisable requires restart so no dice. I'm trying to block the device for another user in ESET and then run the app as this other user while being looged in as primary user.

EDIT : ESET device control did nothing. I think it ignores the rule when you "run as" another user.

Comment: Another approach, can I disable and then enable the device with a batch file (.bat)?

Comment: Added more info.